# How to manage many openAsync() calls in a big Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sqlite

I used openAsync() function many times in my application to open SQLite connection with a success. But lately I added more code that also uses openAsync() and now I obtain this error:

```
Error: Error #3110: Operation cannot be performed while SQLStatement.executing is true.
at Error$/throwError()
at flash.data::SQLStatement/checkReady()
at flash.data::SQLStatement/execute()
at Function/com.lang.SQL:SQLErrorStack/deleteAllRecordsFromErrorStackTable/com.lang.SQL:connOpenHandler()[C:\work\Lang\trunk\actionscript\src\com\lang\SQL\SQLErrorStack.as:466]
```

It looks like the previous code didn't finish executing while another has started.
My question is: Why the execution of code in the second connection was rejected? I expected that some kind of a queue mechanism is used but it isn't. I looked everywhere for a solution how to cope with this problem but I failed. Can you help?

Can one opened DB connection solve the problem? What changes to my code should I apply then?

This is the code similar to this, that appears a few times in my application.

```
var SQLquery:String;
SQLquery = "DELETE FROM ErrorStackTable";
        var sqlConn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
        sqlConn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, connOpenHandler);

        var dbFile:File = new File();
        dbFile.nativePath = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.databaseFullPath_conf+"\\"+FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.databaseName_conf;

        sqlConn.openAsync(dbFile); // openDB
        sqlSelect = new SQLStatement();
        sqlSelect.sqlConnection = sqlConn;
        sqlSelect.text = SQLquery;

        function connOpenHandler(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            sqlSelect.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultSQLHandler);
            sqlSelect.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            sqlSelect.execute();
        }
```

Comment: You can't hold on to the connection?  In almost all db platforms, securing a connection is a time-intensive process.

Comment: I could accept such time-intensive process as a solution if only it worked. If you look at the code you will notice that I would have to restructure my code. Is it really worth it? I don't have many DB connections but they are very consecutive.

Comment: Are you calling to excecute the next query after your result or fault handler has fired?

Comment: No, because I expected that some kind of queue exists in SQLite database. What's more I expect this kind of putting queries into the queue managed by me would be difficult to implement. Or I am wrong.

Comment: I have found this: http://dispatchevent.org/roger/technique-semaphores/ Would it be useful?

Comment: You don't need anything as heavy as a semaphore.  Just use an array containing the statements you want to execute, and in your run()/execute() method, invoke "somearray.pop" to get the next statement to run.

Comment: Do you think I will have to use a timer, that will constantly check if there are new items in the array?

Answer (score 0):

In Big Flex Applications  Try To Avoid openAsync(db) calls because of the reusablity of the SQL code , if u have many sql statments to be executed then you should define more and more sql statments . and if you have dynamic result [Array] getting from web service (RPC ) then you  will surely get an error although it is successful  Execution and array insertion in the database will be fail .. Just  Look at
 the link [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270092/how-to-insert-data-from-dynamic-array-to-sqlite-db-getting-from-webservice-using) You Will Get your answer

I just changed  **`conn.openAsync(db);`** to **`conn.open(db);`** and it worked

Thanks

Comment: Notice that openAsync() solves problems with freezing the application if there is a lot of data to be saved. What's more it often happens that the error like this happens: operation is still executing. So I think it may be a problem or I am wrong. I've known this from my experience. That's amazing that there is no solution to this problem. I looked everywhere how to organize the SQLite code for big application. I'm really disappointed.